# JSON Many to Many RelationShip Group By

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, many-to-many, json-query

I'm trying to create an SQL query allowing me to do this:

I have 3 tables in SQL Server 2017:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCTCATEGORY]
(
    [PROD_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CAT_ID] [int] NOT NULL 

    CONSTRAINT [PK_PRODUCTCATEGORY] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PROD_ID] ASC, [CAT_ID] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CATEGORY]
(
    [CAT_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CAT_TITLE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CATEGORY] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CAT_ID] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCT]
(
    [PROD_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PROD_TITLE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_PRODUCT] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PROD_ID] ASC)
)
```

- A product can have 1 to many categories
- A category can have 1 to many products

| PROD_ID | PROD_TITLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Book 1 |
| 2 | Book 2 |

| CAT_ID | CAT_TITLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat 1 |
| 2 | Cat 2 |
| 3 | Cat 3 |

| PROD_ID | CAT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |

I would like to retrieve this:

```
| CAT_ID  |CAT_TITLE | PRODUCTS                                                                |
|:------- |:--------:|:------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1       | Cat 1    |[{"PROD_ID":1,"PROD_TITLE":"Book 1"},{"PROD_ID":2,"PROD_TITLE":"Book 2"}]|
| 2       | Cat 2    |[{"PROD_ID":1,"PROD_TITLE":"Book 1"}]                                    |
| 3       | Cat 3    |[{"PROD_ID":2,"PROD_TITLE":"Book 2"}]                                    |
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this, using FOR JSON:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

I think something like this might work:

```
SELECT c.CAT_ID, c.CAT_TITLE, 
(
   SELECT p.PROD_ID, p.PROD_TITLE
   FROM PRODUCT p
   JOIN PRODUCTCATEGORY pc ON pc.PROD_ID = p.PROD_ID
   WHERE pc.CAT_ID = c.CAT_ID
   FOR JSON PATH
) AS ProductsAsJson
FROM CATEGORY c
```